# Unable to connect to Redshift via SQL workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect to my redshift server but unsure where I am going wrong. I believe the driver, url and credentials are correct. I even set inbound rule for the VPC to allow all traffic, all protocol and all ranges.

May I ask if I can get some suggestions on how to proceed onwards?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error do you see or does it just time out when connecting?  From where are you trying to connect - from the Internet, from a tunnel, from within the VPC?

Comment: Is your Redshift cluster in a **Public Subnet** and is it configured as `Publicly Accessible = Yes`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you! that's exactly it. I thought allowing all traffic, protocols and port ranges to VPC would be sufficient, guess not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an Amazon Redshift database accessible from the Internet, it should be launched in a **public subnet** and configured for `Publicly Available = Yes`.

Placing a database in a public subnet can be quite risky, since it removes a layer of security. Therefore, I encourage you to **restrict access as much as possible via the Security Group**, such as only allowing access from your own IP address.

The `Publicly Available = Yes` option makes the DNS Name of the database resolvable from the Internet, returning a **public IP address**. If the option is set to `No`, then only a private IP address is returned.